# GWT Web Application with Hibernate and JBoss 5.1

Tags: hibernate, gwt, jpa, jboss, persistence

I have a GWT web aplicaction that is using Hibernate for JPA and JBoss 5.1 for server.

I don't have any problem when I deploy the WAR file in JBoss Server. Everything works well. But When I try to use the GWT Eclipse plugin to avoid the GWT compile time, the Hibernate stop working. I got the log message "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named xptoPU".

At this point I had the JBoss 5.1 in my class path. Then I tried to remove that putting the Hibernate JARs in my WEB-INF/lib folder. This didn't work too, but the log message was different. Now tells me that the EntityManager can't load the persistence unit.

BTW, When I use GlassFish and EclipseLink I don't have any problem doing these kind of stuff...

There's any way to put this working? I really need to avoid the GWT compile time :/

Answer (score 1):

dont use jboss for dev servlet container. its way to slow. You should be using jetty that gwt dev mode uses. This takes about 2 sec to start. Getting dev mode to work with jboss is pretty much impossible due to all of the dependencies.

Also you only need to do a gwt compile when your changing code in the client package. Make sure your project is set to auto build and then just launch your project into the servlet container. Also use the eclipse plugin run jetty run. It lets you do a right click run as to deploy directly without having to build a war. This is very fast.

If you tweak your gwt compiler you should be able to get the comp time around 25 to 60 sec. Which is pretty fast IMO since you can work on two things, and alternate between them.

When your ready to smoke test in production, roll up your EAR and deploy that into your dev server that your team is using. Long as you properly configure your db resource xml file properly and store it in the right location (usually in the root package; within resources package) it should just work.

I know this prolly not exactly what your looking for but its what we pretty much all do. Just do a google search for speed up gwt compile times.

Comment: I already knew some of these tips. The problem is that these project depends of some modules that are prepared to work in JBoss. Since I already had successfully use tomcat and GlassFish in another projects I thought that I  wouldn't have any problem with JBoss... I'll try jetty, thanks :)

Comment: if you can get it to work in jetty then you should be fine with dev mode. We have that same exact issue in our enterprise setup. We import the jboss dependecies into our project directly and then just exclude them when we roll our production build up. I prefer jetty as its extremely fast for startup and resource caching.

Comment: I can't put these working with jetty. The problem is when I run as webapp in jetty the EntityManagerFactory cannot build my persistence unit... But when I deploy as a WAR file it works fine :/

Comment: I use the EMF fine in my jetty environment, make sure you are using version 8 of jetty and have JNDI turned on. This is in your advanced options. and make sure parentload priority is turned off i think this tells jetty to build it as a war. also check your jetty classpath to make sure your persistance libs are included